# controller isn't updating values in the database when using the .increment method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails controller that isn't updating the value in the database when I call the `.increment!` method.

The funny thing is, the same code works in the `create` method

Here's the controller code

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_request, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /requests
  # GET /requests.json
  def index
    @requests = Request.all
  end

  # GET /requests/1
  # GET /requests/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /requests/new
  def new
    @request = Request.new
  end

  # GET /requests/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /requests
  # POST /requests.json
  def create
    @request = Request.new(request_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save

        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @request }

        @request.increment!(:voteCount)

      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /requests/1
  # PATCH/PUT /requests/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.update(request_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @request }

      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /requests/1
  # DELETE /requests/1.json
  def destroy
    @request.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to requests_url, notice: 'Request was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_request
      @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def request_params
      params.require(:request).permit(:artist, :title, :voteCount)
    end

    def upvote
      puts 'upvote'
      request = Request.find(params[:request_id])

      render json: { voteCount: request.voteCount }
      @request.increment!(:voteCount)
      request.increment!(:voteCount)
      request.save
      request.reload

  end


end
```

Here's the html

```
<tbody>
  <% @requests.each do |request| %>
 <tr data-request-id="<%= request.id %>">
   <td id="artist" style="text-align: center"><%= request.artist %></td>
   <td id="songTitle" style="text-align: center"><%= request.title %></td>
   <td style="text-align: center" id="voteCount<%= request.id %>"><%= request.voteCount %></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><%= button_to 'Vote', request_upvote_path(request.id), remote: true, method: :post, onclick: "upvote(#{request.id})", class: 'upvote', id:"voteButton#{request.id}" %></td> </tr>
   <% end %>
```

Here's the JS that updates the count on the page

```
$("#ClickMe").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 



function upvote(id) {
    var count = document.getElementById("voteCount" + id).innerHTML;
    count = parseInt(count);
    count = count + 1;
    count = count.toString();
    document.getElementById("voteCount" + id).innerHTML = count;
    document.getElementById("voteButton" + id).disabled = true;
 }
```

Adding routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :requests do
    post 'upvote', to: 'requests#upvote'
  end
end
```

Comment: It might help to add your server log from when the "Vote" button is clicked.

Comment: Nothing happens in the server when it’s clicked, the html is updated by a JS method, but nothing happens on the server. Am I missing something in the route maybe? The method seems like it executed the JSON update but nothing else

Comment: I actually think this might be something with my route since it doesnt seem to be triggering anything on the server side. I'll add the route code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 question before answer your question

1. Did that code return any error, while you run it?
2. Why do you have two `increment!` method?
3. You have `@requests` in your ERB template which is problem because you don't have `@requests` instance variable in your controller.

[`.increment!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment-21) is correct method for voting; however, you need to save it because

> Only `attribute` is updated; the record itself is not saved.

So, you need to save your record to database

```rb
def upvote
  @request = Request.find(params[:request_id])
  @request.increment!(:voteCount)
  @request.save

  render json: { voteCount: @request.voteCount }
end
```

---

Possible links about the topic:

- [Ruby on Rails: strange voting increment behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349064/ruby-on-rails-strange-voting-increment-behavior)
- [Ruby on Rails Increment Counter in Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019085/ruby-on-rails-increment-counter-in-model)
- [How do I implement voting in Rails](https://gorails.com/forum/how-do-i-implement-voting-in-rails)

Comment: According to the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!), `increment!` does a `save`, no? Perhaps a `reload` is required?

Comment: Well, I gave you a link from [api.rubyonrails.org](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment-21).

Comment: i try manually reloading the page and the count still says the same. I also check the database just to confirm. There is no error when I run the app and click the button. I'll update my post to give a broader sense of what I'm doing